# hows to apply gzip for css and js on joomla 1.5

Tags: php, gzip, joomla1.5

I'm trying to compress some files to increase the speed of my site. I'm doing this in the htaccess file and it is working for everything but a few files.

i have enable gzip from admin section.

hows to enable gzip in joomla 1.5  for css and js file ?

Comment: Have you looked here? http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=343940

Comment: yes , but not able to find htacess file in root of joomla also looked http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/

Comment: I have used the information given on that 'betterexplained' site on multiple joomla sites, it works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also experiencing the same problem..since .htacess file where i have to apply the code

Answer (score 1):

Have you check joomla extension page?
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/site-performance

There are some plugins that can do that for you.